# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{e^n - e^{\frac1n + n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

So far I've tried: $${e^n - e^{\frac1n + n}} = e^n(1- e^{\frac1n}).$$ Then appling l'Hopitals rule to $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^n(1- e^{\frac1n}) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{(1- e^{\frac1n})}{e^{-n}},$$ I have not found success. Is there another way to manipulate the expression to be able to apply l'Hopitals? I know the limit should approach -$\infty$. To clarify, I can use l'Hopital.

Comment: Use the inequality $e^x>1+x$ for all positive $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$${e^n - e^{\frac1n + n}}=e^n \left(1-e^{\frac1n}\right)=-\frac{e^n}n \frac{e^{\frac1n}-1}{\frac1n}$$

then use standard limits.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $-\infty$.

The trick is to factor out an $e^{n}$ term, and force L'Hopital's Rule by writing the expression as a fraction. We have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n} - e^{\frac{1}{n} + n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n}\left(1 - e^{1/n}\right)$$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{n}\left(1 - e^{1/n}\right)\left(1 + e^{1/n}\right)}{(1 + e^{1/n})} $$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{n} \left(1 - e^{2/n}\right)}{1 + e^{1/n}} $$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{n} - e^{n + \frac{2}{n}}}{1 + e^{1/n}}.$$

By L'Hopital's Rule, the above expression equals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{n} - e^{n + \frac{2}{n}}\left(1 - \frac{2}{n^{2}}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n^{2}} \cdot e^{1/n}}  \\[1em] $$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-n^{2} \left( e^{n} - e^{n + \frac{2}{n}}\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right)\right)}{e^{1/n}}.$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $e^{1/n}$ approaches $1$, and the numerator clearly approaches $-\infty$.

Therefore, the answer is $-\infty$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! A question though -- why does the numerator approach $-\infty$? $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} -n^2\left(e^n-e^{n+\frac{2}{n}}(1-\frac{2}{n})\right) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}-n^2(e^n)(1-e^{\frac{2}{n}}) =  \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}-n^2 (e^n)(1-1)= 0.$$ I 'm having trouble algebraically getting there

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} -n^{2}\left(e^{n}\right)\left(1 - e^{2/n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} -n^{2} \left(e^{n} - e^{2/n + n}\right) =  \ldots$$

Comment: My apologies, but I still don't see it. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^n - e^{\frac{2}{n} + n}$ is similar to the limit I originally am tying to prove